# Shopware 6 app storefront build shipping problem

Tags: shopware6

my Shopware 6 App has custom JavaScript and is built via bin/build-storefront.sh which generates a js file inside the dist folder, which I have to ship. I just zip the folder my_app inside custom/apps which then has the root elements manifest.xml and Resources. There could not be a problem I hope.
I noticed that the spelling of my app is my_app, with underscore. But the dist file is spelled my-app.js with a dash. I tried switching it back to underscore, but it did not work either.
So the problem is, that the code is not executed, only if I run build-storefront.sh at the destination shop as well. I am using the latest dockware dev shop (6.5.4.1).
Thank you very much for help.